# Automate Azure Function App to Start/Stop using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I want some Azure function to be start/stop if they are idle for 30 minutes using powershell.

Can it be possible to automate using idle time, if not normally can we automate start/stop of Azure function using Power shell.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions, when run on the Consumption Plan, have this as a default feature. Not with that specific timeframe, but the instance of your Function App  is stopped after being inactive for a certain amount of time and automatically started as soon as a trigger occurs.

> Scale automatically and only pay for compute resources when your functions are running.
>
> On the Consumption plan, instances of the Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events.
>
> ✔ Default hosting plan.
> ✔ Pay only when your functions are running.
> ✔ Scales automatically, even during periods of high load.

Source: [Azure Functions hosting options - Overview of plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#overview-of-plans)

Also interesting: [Azure Functions Consumption plan hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan)

> When you're using the Consumption plan, instances of the Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events. The Consumption plan is the fully *serverless* hosting option for Azure Functions.